# GraphQL for .NET core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, controller, graphql

I'm newbie in GraphQL for .NET core.
I Added GraphQL in my source but it not into controller when debug. It went to my ObjectGrapType
See the image detail :

1. Click start in GrapiQL
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roxkq.png)
2. Then It not go to controller
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqiEE.png)
   3.It go to the Order Query
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/886jk.png)

I don't understand why it happens

Can't you help me check that.
Is that an error or not?
My startUp class :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDiscoveryClient(Configuration);
        services.AddCustomDbContext(Configuration);
        services.AddControllers()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(o => o.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
        services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
        services.AddCustomSwagger();

        services.AddCustomDependency(Configuration);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseDiscoveryClient();

        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger();
        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
        // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
        });
        app.UseGraphiQl("/graphql");
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseGraphQL<OrderQuerySchema>();
        app.UseGraphQLPlayground(options: new GraphQLPlaygroundOptions());
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

Thanks very much and have a good day

LamNV

Answer (score 0):

Didn't get it. what lib do you use - GraphQL.Net?
Btw, based on GraphQL.net is existed a more elegant solution that allows starting much easier. You just have to define schemas in JSON file and set DB-connection string ([NReco.GraphQL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NReco.GraphQL/))